# Alfresco processdefinition xml script

Tags: alfresco

Within an Alfresco processdefinition xml script, what are the possible method calls for a NodeRef var?
For example, if I have a var defined like this:

var node = utils.getNodeFromString(library);

I know I can use methods like "move" and "save", but what is the full list
of methods? (Where is this documented?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find an exhaustive documentation of the Alfresco JavaScript API in the [official docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/references/API-JS-Scripting-API.html) or [in the wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API).

Make sure you're looking at the documentation version that matches your Alfresco instance, there might be relevant differences in the API.

Comment: Thanks, what I am really trying to do is this:
1. I have an existing processdefinition.xml file
2. It does a node update by removing the existing node and then moving a new node into its place.
var existingNode = utils.getNodeFromString(library);
var newNode = utils.getNodeFromString(tempLibrary);
existingNode.remove;
newNode.move(existingNode);

The only problem with this approach is that, when it's finished, all of the files/folders
in existingNode have new create dates (the date/time when the new files were created).
I want to be able to preserve the create dates from the original node.

Comment: The `cm:created` property is [`protected`](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml), i.e. read only. There are various ways around this limitation, but that's a completely different topic IMO.